# To find all the overlapping date ranges from a given list of Date Ranges

Tags: java, date

I have a List of BookingDateRange where BookingDateRange is :

```
    public class BookingDateRange {
        private Date fromDate;
        private Date toDate;

        //getters & setters of properties
   }
```

**Requirement:**

1. I need to find if any date overlaps in List of BookingDate say dateRangeList
2. If yes, find all the date ranges pair which overlap say List of String say overlappingDatePairs

**Example1**:

Input1:

dateRangeList[0] = 23 dec 2012- 27 dec 2012

dateRangeList[1] = 14 dec 2012 - 25 dec 2012

dateRangeList[2] = 1 jan 2012 - 23 jan 2012

Output1:

isOverlappingDates = true

overlappingDatePairs = [0_1]

**Example2:**

Input2:

dateRangeList[0] = 23 dec 2012- 27 dec 2012

dateRangeList[1] = 1 jan 2012 - 23 jan 2012

Output2:

isOverlappingDates = false

overlappingDatePairs = []

**My Solution :**

```
/**
 * Checks if any of the dates overlap.
 *
 * @param dateRangeList the date range list
 * @param overlappingDatePairs the overlapping date pairs where overlappingDatePair is stored in the format dateRange1_dateRange2
 * @return true, if any of the dates overlap.
 */

public static boolean isOverlappingDates(
            List<BookingDateRange> dateRangeList,
            List<String> overlappingDatePairs) {

    boolean isOverlap = false;

    for (int index1 = 0; index1 < dateRangeList.size(); index1++) {
        for (int index2 = index1 + 1; index2 < dateRangeList.size(); index2++) {

            // Overlap exists if (StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)

            Date startA = dateRangeList.get(index1).getFromDate();
            Date endA = dateRangeList.get(index1).getToDate();
            Date startB = dateRangeList.get(index2).getFromDate();
            Date endB = dateRangeList.get(index2).getToDate();

            boolean isStartABeforeEndB = (startA.compareTo(endB)) < 0;
            boolean isEndAAfterStartB = (endA.compareTo(startB)) > 0;

            boolean isCurrentPairOverlap = false;

            isCurrentPairOverlap = isStartABeforeEndB && isEndAAfterStartB;

            if (isCurrentPairOverlap) {
                overlappingDatePairs.add(index1 + "_" + index2);
                isOverlap = true;
            }
        }

    }
    return isOverlap;

    }
```

The complexity of this approach is O(n ^2). Is a better complexity possible ? Could not arrive at an algorithm with a better complexity.

Did come across a few solutions at SO. But none of them could cater to the requirement completely.

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: Looks like the complexity is O(n^2) not O(2^n)  **Edited** :D

Comment: @gtgaxiola  Oops.. typo.. Yes.. O(n^2). Edited in the ques.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's O(nlog(n)), or obviously if there are lots of collisions, it's O(number of collisions). A company I used to work for used something similar to this as an interview question.

```
private static class BookingTuple implements Comparable<BookingTuple> {
    public final Date date;
    public final boolean isStart;
    public final int id;
    public BookingTuple(Date date, boolean isStart, int id) {
        this.date = date;
        this.isStart = isStart;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BookingTuple other) {
        int dateCompare = date.compareTo(other.date);
        if (dateCompare != 0) {
            return dateCompare;
        } else {
            if (!isStart && other.isStart) {
                return -1;
            } else if (isStart && !other.isStart) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isOverlappingDates(List<BookingDateRange> dateRangeList, List<String> overlappingDatePairs) {
    List<BookingTuple> list = new ArrayList<BookingTuple>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dateRangeList.size(); i++) {
        Date from = dateRangeList.get(i).getFromDate();
        Date to = dateRangeList.get(i).getToDate();
        list.add(new BookingTuple(from, true, i));
        list.add(new BookingTuple(to, false, i));
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    boolean overlap = false;

    HashSet<Integer> active = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (BookingTuple tuple : list) {
        if (!tuple.isStart) {
            active.remove(tuple.id);
        } else {
            for (Integer n : active) {
                overlappingDatePairs.add(n + "_" + tuple.id);
                overlap = true;
            }
            active.add(tuple.id);
        }
    }

    return overlap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do better since you have to compare each BookingDateRange with the others...

So it takes `O(n) comparisons per element`  and you have `n elements`

therefore  `n * n =  O(n^2)`

Comment: Following your logic, sorting also has lower bound of n^2, which is obviously not true. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would trade complexity for memory. It assumes that the range of dates is relatively limited (you are not mixing dates from 5000BC and 6000AD).

1 Create a `Map<String, List<Range>>`.

2 For each of the ranges, pick the first date and convert it into `GregorianCalendar`. Get the date in format "yyyy/MM/dd" (or similar).

2a If the "yyyy/MM/dd" String is already in the Map, add the new Range to the List.

2b If it is not, add the entry with a new List containing the Range.

2c Increase the GregorianCalendar a day. Repeat until last date in the range has been reached.

3 Repeat for all the ranges.

4 List the keys of the Map (if you used the "yyyy/MM/dd" format sorting is trivial). Check the size of the associated list.

Comment: I didn't check the `O(n)` claim so I was thinking about improving a `2^n` complexity (which means additional overhead is usually meaningless). Seeing gtgaxiola's correction, my method is less of an improvement but can still be useful if the number of ranges is high and the dates covered small.