# How to compare 1 set of date with another set of date in SQL Server for overlapping period

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I have two sets of dates. I need to check whether the set A dates overlap on Set B dates in SQL Server

What is the best approach?.

**Set A: (MM/DD/YYYY)**

```
Date from: 1/1/2013  
Date To:   2/15/2013
```

**Set B (MM/DD/YYYY)**

```
Date From : 2/10/2013
Date To : 2/20/2013
```

**UPDATE**
It's a leave application, where if an employee applies leave, I need to check whether the from and to date over laps on any other pending/Approved leave for the same employee. before letting the employee apply his leave.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573512/to-find-all-the-overlapping-date-ranges-from-a-given-list-of-date-ranges).

Comment: Why not use standard SQL server data functions instead of doing this in java ?

Comment: @whowantsakookie. Thanks for pointing. I couldn't find any relevant material in my search.

Comment: What does have to do with `Java` ?

Comment: He's doing it in Java. Or at least that's what I'm assuming.

Comment: @kocko I am developing the application in java, this is a part of the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Given two date ranges (`A` and `B`) you can test whether they overlap by checking if `A` starts before `B` finishes and `A` finishes after `B` starts. Depending on your data, it should be fairly simple to do this in SQL:

```
If Exists
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM LeaveTable
    WHERE State In ('Pending', 'Approved')
    And @ProposedStart < EndDate
    And @ProposedEnd > StartDate
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('The proposed leave overlaps.', 16, 1);
    Return;
END;
```